# Starting a sentence with Besides,

Tags: grammar

I came across a form, and in one section it started, "Besides, I love to travel and talk to friends."

Paragraph prior to this sentence talked about something completely different. It struck me as being wrong. Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Why did it 'strike' you as wrong? Does it seem to violate some rule that you have heard of?

Comment: Thanks Michael. No rules. Just didn't sound / read right as a stand alone sentence. I was just asking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is wrong, but it would suggest several possibilities:

1. I was tired of listening to you, so I abruptly changed the subject.
2. I completely misunderstood what you were saying, so to me this *non sequitur* seemed perfectly consistent with your remarks.
3. I wasn't listening to you closely, so I inadvertently changed the subject.
4. We were entering controversial territory, so I deliberately changed the subject, intending this to be humorous.
5. I was paying attention to you, but what you were saying triggered a logical chain of ideas in my mind. I mentioned the  last of these without realizing you couldn't possibly have followed my train of thought.

Comment: Someone voted this down, but absent an explanation, I don't see why.

Comment: I didn't vote you down. But what the questioner asked was about the use of the word **besides** at the start of a sentence that doesn't relate to the previous sentence. You have given a number of examples that may have led to the speaker's reaction without addressing the question. In grammatical terms, was it wrong to do so?

Comment: All of my examples were by way of showing how the use of *Besides* at the beginning could be perfectly valid.

Comment: True, but they didn't address the question. Let's leave it there.